# How do I add payment details in Setup intent Method - Stripe Python

Tags: python, stripe-payments, payment

Hola I would like to Add payment details in SetupIntent.create Method.

I would do that with API Using something like this :

```
import requests

url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents"
params = {
    "key": "sk_live_xxxxx",
    "payment_method_data[type]": "card",
    "confirm": True,
    "customer": "cu_xxxx",
    "payment_method_data[card][number]": "cc number",
    "payment_method_data[card][exp_month]": "exp_mnth",
    "payment_method_data[card][exp_year]": "exp_year",
    "payment_method_data[card][cvc]": "xxx"
}
response = requests.post(url, params=params).text
print(response)
```

But How do this with Python Stripe Lib?

I tried this Code :

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = "sk_live_xxxxx"

r = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                              payment_method_types=["card"],
                              customer="cu_xxx",
                              confirm=True
    )

print(r)
```

But, How will I add payment details in it?

I checked the the docs & it's examples but it only has examples adding payment method types, not payment details like cc number, cvc, expiry month & year.

I want to add customer & attach payment method & charge him. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a [SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents?lang=python) you're saving customer payment credentials to charge later date, generally off-session. A [PaymentMethod](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create?lang=python) object ID is required when creating (or confirming) a SetupIntent.

It is recommended that you [capture customer payment details](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-collect-card-details) in your front-end application with Stripe.js, and pass the generated PaymentMethod object ID (`pm_xxx`) when creating (or confirming) the SetupIntent. Stripe.js can then handle any required actions on the generated PaymentMethod, such as 3DS authentication.

There's a full SetupIntent integration example [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse), which uses the Python client library with Stripe.js

Comment: Thank you for answering! At first, I don't js. And I tried that method earlier,  but when I try to charge the customer, it says : "No payment Method Found". And please give some examples too 

Comment: @Jainam You can pass an optional [`card` dictionary](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-card) when creating a SetupIntent. This method is **strongly advised against** as you're forgoing any PCI compliance offered by Stripe. Instead you should use Stripe.js to collect payment details. Follow the [link I shared](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) for a full integration example with Python and Stripe.js.